# Gradle / Jenkins JAR Release to GitHub

Tags: java, git, github, jenkins, gradle

I am working on a bunch of projects which are all part of a larger project (pipeline) and thus need to be tested together quite often. Manual tests are not as great as they should be, so I decided to run things in the future using Gradle + Jenkins CI. My first tests were successfuly, unit tests etc are running great and Jenkins builds my JAR files that I want to deploy quite nicely.

Since all my projects are open source and available on GitHub, I'd love to set things up to be published on the GitHub releases page of the respective (sub-) project, e.g. something like this:

- I develop, commit with a Git tag
- Jenkins sees this via a Hook, runs the Gradle Script to build things and upon successful tests publishes the JAR file created in my project to a new release version on GitHub

Unfortunately, this is not working quite as expected, e.g. using the [Plugin here](https://github.com/systemfabrikken/gradle-githubrelease-plugin), which for example only pushed the packaged source code and not the JAR file. Otherwise this works well and I might just have overseen something?

Does someone have experience on this ?

Comment: Why do you need to push the generated JAR file to your Git repository alongside your code ? Note that it is not good practice to push heavy files such as jars in your Git repo, you should instead send them somewhere else, maybe in a Repository Manager such as [Artifactory](https://www.jfrog.com/open-source/)...

Comment: Hi Pom12 - I think my first comment was not specific enough: I don't want to commit my built JAR file to my repository itself, but rather use e.g. the "Release" section of my project on GitHub to release the JAR file for end users. Of course I could rely on Bintray for example, but I'd rather want to push my built JAR to the projects specific release section for better visibility for end users.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are mistaking what a [Github release](https://help.github.com/articles/creating-releases/) is. From a Github point of view, a release is not some folder where you would deploy your arfifact (e.g. your built Jar) but is basically just a Git tag that points to a certain commit and says "ok, I consider this commit d215465454 to be my release 1.2.3". It is just a pointer to a commit so you can always find the Git history for any specific "release". Please see Git excellent [Tagging documentation](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Basics-Tagging) for more information.

Moreover, you probably shouldn't need to expose the actual jar to your end users. Instead you could rely on Bintray or Artifactory to deploy your actual jar artifact and your end users could configure their gradle build file to depend on your jar.